# Pop!_OS 22.04 trash icon in dock

Tags: dock

After upgrading to Pop!_OS 22.04 (which uses COMSIC interface) there is no trash icon in dock. There is no option in settings to add the trash icon to the dock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out using this command in terminal:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash true
```